# How do I get the size (or length) for URL searchParams?

Tags: javascript

How get size from URLSearchParams? 
I found

```
Array.from(url.searchParams).length
```

this answer in here https://github.com/whatwg/url/issues/163

It most correct answer?

Comment: Probably. Tbh, for simple urls, I just split the query string on '&'.

Comment: You could also loop through the arguments by using the `.forEach()` function.

Comment: or : 
`[...url.searchParams].length`

Answer (score 12):

TL;DR: It depends on whether or not you care about unique keys.

The normal case, in which the searchParams is a map (unique keys), works fine:

```js
const url = new URL("protocol://domain?query=value1&query1=value2&query2=value");
console.log(Array.from(url.searchParams).length);
// Output is 3
```

Yet you need to be careful when searchParams isn't a map:

```js
const url = new URL("protocol://domain?query=value1&query=value2&query2=value");
console.log(Array.from(url.searchParams).length);
// Output is still 3
```

In this case, when converting to an array, the array is 
`[["query", "value1"], ["query", "value2"], ["query2", "value"]]`. This could be quite confusing if you expect searchParams to be a map.

In this case, in order to find the unique keys, you should extract them using something similar to this:

```js
const url = new URL("protocol://domain?query=value1&query=value2&query2=value");
const searchParams = Array.from(url.searchParams);
const searchParamsUniqueKeys = [];

for (const p of searchParams) {
  if (!searchParamsUniqueKeys.includes(p[0])) {
    searchParamsUniqueKeys.push(p[0]);
  }
}
console.log(searchParamsUniqueKeys.length);
// Output is 2
```

Comment: If this answer helped you, please upvote and accept :) @zloctb

Answer (score 7):

This week (May 4th 2023) [size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/size) was released for URLSearchParams in Chrome and Edge.

```
const params = new URLSearchParams("c=4&a=2&b=3&a=1");
// or const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
console.log(params.size; // 4
```

Comment: thanks for pointing this out! I'm confused when I want to use `size` in my ts repo, and got error ts(2339): Property 'size' does not exist on type 'URLSearchParams'. Now it makes sense why I got error, it's just recently launched.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can attain the length of the `searchParams` property using `Array.from(url.searchParams).length`:

Example:

```js
const url = new URL("protocol://domain?query=value1&query=value2&query2=value");
const size = Array.from(url.searchParams).length

console.log(size)
```

You can also use the ES6 [array spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) syntax:

```js
const url = new URL("protocol://domain?query=value1&query=value2&query2=value");
const size = [...url.searchParams].length

console.log(size)
```